xfce4 as default Windowmanager on Rocky Linux 9
Following this setup routine I installed XFCE4 on Rocky Linux 9.
But this does not startup the xfce4-window-manager in init 5.
If I go to init 3 and then startxfce4 as root XFCE4 is being started.
This does not work as normal user.
There I get the error-message "Anzeige kann nicht geöffnet werden".
Which states that the display can not be opened.
So obviously there is something missing to tell the os to use xfce.
On init5 a different WM starts up. From the process list it seems to be gdm based. If I kill gdm-wayland-session the window-manager restarts.
Update:
It is possible to select the cogwheel and select xfce session.
As root this starts up a xfce4-session.
As non-root the screen blanks and then the login screen reappears.

Putting WaylandEnable=false into section [daemon] in the gdm configuration file /etc/gdm/custom.conf did the trick. After that it is possible to select the xfce-desktop after specifying the user login.
Perhaps someone can explain what that switch does...

That switch disables wayland in gdm.

Second edit - reprasing
I think your problem is connected to the gdm - that is usually used for login into Gnome.  It loads additional dependencies, which you don't need for xfce.  For lightweight environment I would use lightweight login manager.
I would ditch it in favour of lightdm which does not need the dependencies that gdm does.
Edit for more information
The LightDM should work out of the box for Xfce.
The configuration for LightDM:

you need to disable gdm with sudo systemctl disable gdm
install lightdm sudo dnf install lightdm
enable lightdm sudo systemctl enable lightdm

If you change the configuration youneed to do sudo systemctl restart lightdm.
The configuration file is at /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
For example:
[Seat:*]
#type=local
#pam-service=lightdm
#pam-autologin-service=lightdm-autologin
#pam-greeter-service=lightdm-greeter
#xserver-command=X
#xmir-command=Xmir
#xserver-config=
#xserver-layout=
#xserver-allow-tcp=false
#xserver-share=true
#xserver-hostname=
#xserver-display-number=
#xdmcp-manager=
#xdmcp-port=177
#xdmcp-key=
greeter-session=lightdm-slick-greeter
#greeter-hide-users=false
#greeter-allow-guest=true
#greeter-show-manual-login=false
#greeter-show-remote-login=true
user-session=default # you need to change it here
#allow-user-switching=true
#allow-guest=true
#guest-session=

Notice: user-session where you specify your desktop. To get the name you can list /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop and if you get the name e.g. xfce.desktop you need to change the configuration to: user-session=xfce.

Can you please explain how to get there and how to enable xfce in lightdm?

@Nils okay, I have added information.

I installed lightdm, removed gdm and tried to log in - throws me back at the login after a black screen - like gdm before I disabled wayland.

@Nils Weird, I have never had issues with it on even on very unique installations. Could tell me more details about your X.org installation? Do you have any part of Wayland installed?

groupinstall "Xfce" "base-x" was the setup. So base-x probably contains Wayland and gdm.

gdm can start any type of desktop session, it isn’t GNOME-specific.

@StephenKitt it can, but it loads the gnome dependencies with it.

@Nils so did you have to disable the Wayland with the lightdm?

@tukan you wrote “that is good only to log into Gnome”, that’s what I commented on — gdm can log into other setups than GNOME. It does depend on a bunch of GNOME libraries and services, but those are only used for gdm, they’re not enforced on whatever environment is started after login.

@StephenKitt I'll reprase it.  Any login manager can be used for any GUI (at least I don't know a combination that would not work). You could use lightdm for Gnome too, but why would you do that, beside having some issues, if you have gdm at your disposal?  I don't see a reason why you should use gdm (beside having it already installed) for xfce as OP wanted.  In the end, you can use SDDM for Gnome if you want.

I could not start xfce with lightdm. Where would I disable Wayland in lightdm?

@Nils could you share your Xorg configuration?

@Nils The reason why I'm asking for the configuration is you may have incompatible configuration of your Xorg

What do you want to see? Xorg has many files and config locations. None of them have been touched.

@Nils sorry for late answer, but I forgot about it.  I remember there were issues with mouse so any location that contains the mouse configuration
